# Navigate Hamburger Button to MasterDetailPage.Master Part?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a hamburger icon which I will use it to navigate masterdetailpage.master part. I couldnt make sure how to write syntax under of the click event. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: it should automatically display the Master when clicked

Comment: @Jason Actually I disable the navigationbar of the top. Then I create a ImageButton inside the pancakeview. So it is just a visually existing there

Comment: that's the kind of relevant information you should include in your post without people having to ask for it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterdetailpage.ispresented?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @Jason doesnt work :(  I used that one "(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = false;"

Comment: Setting it to false will **hide** the Master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the custom renderer to reset the hamburger icon of imagebutton.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage ), typeof(MasterDetailPageRenderer_Droid))]
namespace MasterDetailPageDemo.Droid
{
class MasterDetailPageRenderer_Droid:MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    public Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    public Activity context;
    public MasterDetailPageRenderer_Droid(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }      

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        context = (Activity)Forms.Context;
        toolbar = context.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Droid.Resource.Id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as Android.Widget.ImageButton;

                var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;
                if (drawerArrow == null)
                    continue;

                imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Forms.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.star_small));
            }
        }
    }
}
```